# PHP - PDO SQLSRV - Connection string is not valid [87]

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I´m trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 via PHP. I used the following code:

```
try {
    $server = "servername.do.ma.in\\MSSQLSERVER";
    $user = "username";
    $pass = "password";
    $db = "databasename";

    $dbh= new PDO('sqlsrv:Server = ' . $server . '; Database = ' . $db, $user, $pass);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

But when i run this code i get the following error:

```
 SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87].
```

Does someone know this error and know what to do?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Solution:**

The Port was not defined. The following code worked for me.
I´ve added the Port 1433 to the $server Variable.

```
$server = "servername.do.ma.in, 1433";
    $user = "username";
    $pass = "password";
    $db = "databasename";

    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server={$server};Database={$db};", $user, $pass);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
$dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server={$server};Database={$db};", $user, $pass);
```

If it's still not valid, there's something wrong with your connection variables.

**EDIT**:

This looks similar to your problem:

http://laravel.io/forum/01-20-2015-sql-server-2012-db-connection-with-laravel-42

Comment: I still get the error, may this error be caused by wrong logindata? Or a wrong authentication?

Comment: @JoshuaH. It's possible. Have you looked at the link I posted in my edit?

Comment: That works! Thanks. I will add the solution to my answer.